# Which encoder does Android MediaRecorder use?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediarecorder, video-encoding, android-mediarecorder

Does anyone know which audio/video encoders does `MediaRecorder` use?

I know we can choose the audio / video mimeTypes with `mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder()` and `mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder()`:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

But this won't tell me which encoder **implementation** is being used, as each device can have multple encoders for H264 (for example, a hardware accelerated one and a software one like `OMX.google.h264.encoder`).

Is there a way to know this?

Can anyone link to native source code where we can discover this?

When using low-level `MediaCodec`, we can access all encoders through `MediaCodecList`, get their name and capabilities, and finally instantiate the correct `MediaCodec`. I'm sure that `MediaRecorder` is doing the same in native code, I just can't find any source code reference. Thanks!

The answers I would expect are...

- MediaRecorder just uses the first matching encoder, just like using `MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(type)`
- MediaRecorder explicitly prefers hardware encoders
- Something else

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this: https://source.android.com/devices/media

Comment: @MorrisonChang no, that's interesting, thanks! But it doesn't tell me how MediaRecorder chooses its encoder as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaRecoders native implementation is [StagefrightRecorder.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmediaplayerservice/StagefrightRecorder.cpp).
In method [setupVideoEncoder](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmediaplayerservice/StagefrightRecorder.cpp#1643), [line #1782](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libmediaplayerservice/StagefrightRecorder.cpp#1782) you can see it is using `MediaCodecSource::Create` with a format that has 'video/avc' as 'mime' (Line #1660).

In [MediaCodecSource.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecSource.cpp) in method initEncoder in [line #515](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecSource.cpp#515) the best suited encoder is selected.

How the Codec gets selected can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp#322)

I hope this helps navigating through androids native media impementations.

Comment: Thanks very much! So by following all the links, the interesting part is the integer flag which gets passed around and can contain `MediaCodecList::kPreferSoftwareCodecs` or `MediaCodecList:: kHardwareCodecsOnly` or none. But it seems that in our case none of these two will be set - could you confirm?

Comment: If this is true, I'd say MediaRecorder just takes the first matching encoder it finds (which presumably comes from the vendor list in `etc/media_codecs.xml`)

Comment: I can't confirm, because neither do i work for a HW manufacturer nor for AOSP. My guess wold be that it's up to HW manufacturers to explicitly set these flags for their devices. I think i read somewhere that Androids methods for selecting codecs automatically are always supposed to default to a HW codec and fall back to a software codec if there is no HW codec present. As it's supposed to be, but i can't back that up with a source.

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like this flag starts as 0 in StagefrightRecorder and is not modified after. Anyway, just to give an answer to my question, I think we can say that "MediaRecorder uses the first codec that [configures correctly](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecSource.cpp#515), in a list that's probably ordered by vendors".

Answer (score 2):

**Some other thoughts on this**, and other work with a Media. Which used `ExoPlayer`. We had to deal with `MediaCodec` selection and force this player to use tunneling codecs. In internal implementation, they are doing exactly what you mentioned.

Retrieving complete list of possible secure codecs for next forwarding and where `ExoPlayer` just selection first one from the list.

```
MediaCodecListCompat mediaCodecList = Util.SDK_INT >= 21
    ? new MediaCodecListCompatV21(secure) : new MediaCodecListCompatV16();
```

....

```
List<MediaCodecInfo> decoderInfos = getDecoderInfos(mimeType, secure);
return decoderInfos.isEmpty() ? null : decoderInfos.get(0);
    getCodecCapabilities(int index, String type);
```

I still wondering, there is no other priority by choosing one over another codec. We could assume, it's because of native part, where vendor codecs goes first obviously. And (should be) better for this particular device.

---

**Back to `MediaRecorder`.** What I have found following `MediaRecorder` implementation in native part with `native_setup` in the JNI `JMediaCodec` which delegates native part with `MediaCodec`. This implementation uses reference [ACodec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/437ced8a14944bf5450df50c5e7e7a6dfe20ea40/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp) what is the most interesting place.

Here you can find usage of [MediaCodecList](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/437ced8a14944bf5450df50c5e7e7a6dfe20ea40/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp) and external Media services, codec allocation and finally [OMXCodec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/c558fa8/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp) where all the selection and matching requests happens. So the same codec list retrived from the [MediaCodecList](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp) via other implementation`IMediaPlayerService`, which holds information about available codec names. I could check later, what else we can find.

---

**UPDATE.** So what we found, is not like exact answer to the question. But all the magic you need located in few files. 1) Codec usage, and partial selection (comparator between codecs, and other) could be found in the [OMXCodec](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/c558fa8/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp). 2) List of codecs with helpers functions located in the [MediaCodecList](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/MediaCodecList.cpp) And finally 3) Implementation of the `IMediaPlayerService` contains complete unsorted codecs with their capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for interesting links!